# Boot into emergency mode because of nouveau: Error parsing PCC subspaces from PCCT

Tags: boot, grub2, nvidia, kubuntu, nouveau

I installed kubuntu 15.04 and upgraded it to 15.10. I was able to boot normally into kubuntu a few times but suddenly it started to boot only in emergency mode showing this:

```
[    2.932200]Error parsing PCC subspaces from PCCT
[    3.245398]nouveau ![  DEVICE][0000:06:00.0] unknown Maxwell chipset
[    3.245406]nouveau E[  DEVICE][0000:06:00.0] unknown chipset, 0x118010a2
[    3.245410]nouveau E[     DRM] failed to create 0x00000080, -22
welcome to emergency mode! blablabla...
```

I reinstalled it all, it worked normally but after some reboots, it's back and this error is showing again :( I also searched in the great internet. Found some things about adding "nomodeset" to grub but it didn't make it.

Thanks in advance for any help!

My laptop is a Lenovo ThinkPad Yoga 15 (20DQ/003QMZ)
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 5500, NVIDIA GeForce 840M

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved by disabling fast startup on Windows 10 (dual installation).

To achieve that in Windows open the *Control Panel*, go to *All Control Panel Items > Power Options > System Settings > Change settings that are currently unavailable (UAC)* and uncheck *Fast Startup (recommended)*.