# Ubuntu installing Error ! ~ Error parsing

Tags: system-installation, 15.10, asus

I've tried to install Ubuntu 15.10 x64 on my new laptop for the first time.
I used a usb stick to do that but it fails each time I try.
I always get this error once I boot to the usb :

[image]

```
[0.034372] Ignoring BGRT: invalid status 0 (expected 1)
[4.766834] Error parsing PCC subspaces from PCCT
```

Laptop Info :
ASUS G751JY
BIOS : American Megatrends Inc. G751JY.211, 02-Nov-15

please help me , what should I do in this case ??

Comment: does you computer comes with dedicated graphics card?

Comment: nvidia gtx 980m O.o

Comment: [Here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/702917/boot-into-emergency-mode-because-of-nouveau-error-parsing-pcc-subspaces-from-pc) it was solved by disabling «fast startup». Check for it in EFI *(could be named like «fast boot», or something alike)*, and see if it would work.

Comment: when you boot and see grub press the E key.
Add `nouveau.modeset=0` to the end of the `linuz` line - press F10 to boot.

Comment: Hi-Angel : Sorry , bro that didn't fix it :(

Comment: edward torvalds : Thank you very much :D :D , That worked .. now I'm inside my potrable ubuntu, heading to install. Thanks again <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you boot from USB and see grub press the `E` key. Add `nouveau.modeset=0` to the end of the `linuz` line then press F10 to boot.