# Error Parsing PCC subspaces from PCCT

Tags: boot, error-handling

Booting up anew my dual-boot laptop, I was greeted with these errors:

```
Error parsing PCC subspaces from PCCT
[drm:gen8_irq_handler [i915]] *ERROR* The master control interrupt lied (SDE)!
[drm:gen8_irq_handler [i915]] *ERROR* The master control interrupt lied (SDE)!
fsck from util-linux 2.26.2
/dev/sda7: clean 403546/6037504 files, 6026588/24142080 blocks
i2c_hid i2c-INVN6500:00: unexpected HID descriptor bcdVersion (0x31a8)
[drm:gen8_irq_handler [i915]] *ERROR* The master control interrupt lied (SDE)!
```

What followed was a root console. The only things I remember doing that could have caused this on the previous boot are:

1. Run the latest Ubuntu base updates, which I think included a kernel update to something like 4.30
2. Change the dm from lightDM to GDM. I have since run the  `dkpg-reconfigure lightdm` command to change it back to no avail. Another symptom is that the `systemctl reboot` fails (goes back to the root console).

What is it that I have done wrong (so I can avoid it in the future) and how may I fix it?

EDIT: Upon further investigation, it was discovered that Ubuntu boots the GUI ok after a clean shutdown on the Windows side. However, it still threw the same errors, it just called the master control interrupt a liar a few times less. A remedy is still desired.

Comment: Is https://askubuntu.com/questions/702917/boot-into-emergency-mode-because-of-nouveau-error-parsing-pcc-subspaces-from-pc of any help?

Comment: Or http://askubuntu.com/q/670509/49860?