# Ubuntu won't start/load

Tags: boot, dual-boot

I have a Lenovo X240 laptop that has dual boot (Windows and Ubuntu), but Ubuntu won't start (Windows works fine).

I get stuck on a black screen with the following followed by a blinking cursor:

```
[0.142165] Error parsing PCC subspaces from PCCT

Busybox v1.22.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.22.0-15ubuntu1) built-in shell (ash)
Enter'help' for a list of built-in commands.

(initramfs)
```

Comment: Hi, I think we would need some more information to solve your problem. What graphics card are you using, and which graphics driver do you have installed? What version of Ubuntu are you running? Make sure that you have fastboot and secureboot disabled in the BIOS.

Comment: I believe the graphics card is: "Intel HD Graphics 4400 (Integrated Card)"

I'm not sure what graphics driver is installed. How can I find that out? Can I find that out?

I think I was running 16.04 LTS

How do disable fastboot and secureboot in BIOS?

Comment: I just found out that secure boot is disabled, but I am not sure about fastboot.

Comment: FYI, this is the computer I am having the problem with: https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=9SIA7RB4W47045&Tpk=9SIA7RB4W47045

Comment: fastboot is sometimes called fast startup in some BIOSes, I usually find it under something along the lines of "Windows settings" in the BIOS.

Comment: fastboot is already disabled.

Comment: Check out the following link and see if it helps.
http://askubuntu.com/questions/670509/error-parsing-pcc-subspaces-from-pcct-acpi-pcc-probe-failed

Comment: I'm not really sure what to do with the suggestions in that link

Comment: This solved it: http://askubuntu.com/questions/137655/boot-drops-to-a-initramfs-prompts-busybox