# Ubuntu Server installer garbled text / glitch art - how to install?

Tags: grub2, system-installation, uefi, lenovo, nvme

I am trying to install Ubuntu Server 17.10 on a new Lenovo P920 Workstation with a Samsung NVMe SSD hard disk drive. I tried Debian 9.3 first, but that did not recognize the SSD; Next try goes to Ubuntu Server 17.10 because I figured I try the most recent kernel I can easily get my hands on.

Unfortunately I do not get far - Grub works, but soon after grub the installer resets the graphics mode and I only get garbled text. I have experimented (i.e. edited the Grub command line) with different `GFXMODE` and `GFXPAYLOAD` settings, but they at most change the graphics directly after executing the grub command line (pressing `F10` to boot) - then the Ubuntu installer resets the graphics mode (i guess?) and I get glitch art again.

1. What else could I try to install Ubuntu Server?
2. Can I find out whether the SSD is supported so I know if it even makes sense keep trying to work around the current graphics problem?

[image: Ubuntu Server 17.10 Installer on Lenovo P920 Workstation]

Answer (score 1):

Adding `nomodeset` to the kernel command line did the trick! Thanks to http://www.rodsbooks.com/linux-uefi/ (via https://askubuntu.com/a/842916/249197)

It says:

> Fixing blank displays—A problem that many people had through much of 2013 (but with decreasing frequency since then) was blank displays when booted in EFI mode. **Sometimes this problem can be fixed by adding `nomodeset` to the kernel's command line.** You can do this by typing e to open a simple text editor in GRUB. In many cases, though, you'll need to research this problem in more detail, because it often has more hardware-specific causes.

(btw, the SSD *is* supported in Ubuntu 17.10)

Comment: Another maybe interesting thing about this box - The only successful boot after installation so far is the stock `4.13.0-16` kernel with `nomodeset` option. The (automatically installed) `4.13.0-32` kernel does throw a general protection fault and `soft lockup cpu #12 stuck for 23s`) (with or without nomodeset).

I never had it with Ubuntu that a minor (patch) kernel had such a regression. Probably I am overseeing something with how grub2 is installed on that NVMe or so...