# Cannot boot ubuntu 18.04 from USB (Error parsing PCC subspaces from PCCT)

Tags: boot, usb, uefi, windows-10, 18.04

There are a couple of related threads, however, none of them helped me to solve my issue.

The problem:
I have a computer with windows 10. I would like to install the latest ubuntu on it alongside windows, so I downloaded ubuntu and created a bootable USB using the "Startup Disk Creator" on ubuntu 16.04.

I disabled the "fast startup" on windows, inserted the USB and restarted the computer. In the Bios, I then disabled "Fast Boot"

[image]

and "Secure Boot"

[image]

and selected the USB as the preferred Boot option.

The typical starting screen appears and I select "Try ubuntu without installation" and then I get the following screen:
[image]

I then tried it using rufus and chose "GPR partition for UEFI" as suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/842916/374591), resulting in the same screen.

Now I am running out of ideas. My long-term goal is to have ubuntu 18.04 alongside windows 10.

Could anyone suggest steps that solve my issue?

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://askubuntu.com/questions/670509/error-parsing-pcc-subspaces-from-pcct-acpi-pcc-probe-failed

Comment: @Cleb  did you find a solution?

Comment: @W.Dodge: Yes. I had to start with `nomodeset` enabled as described in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/162076/374591). Then it worked perfectly fine.